# JavaScript form validation (check for all letters only)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create one function that will check that a field is not blank, contains only letters and spaces. Validating that the field contains letters and spaces only does not appear to work as anything that's put in the field will return the alert message.

I'm trying to say:

If the name field is NOT letters and spaces then display this alert "...". Else return true.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["newsletterForm"]["name"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
                alert("Name must not be blank");
                return false;
            }
        else if (x!==/^[A-Za-z ]+$/) {
                alert("Name contains invalid characters (letters and spaces only!)")
                return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
```

```html
            <form name="newsletterForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                <label for="name">Name*: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Fill in your name"1> <br><br>
                <label for="email">E-mail*: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Fill in your e-mail address"><br><br>
                <label for="comments">Comments (optional): </label> <br>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Leave us a message"></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: look at jquery validation plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

missing `}` at end of `script` and missing `;` at `else if`

and use `regex` for check `only letter and space`

```js
function validateForm() {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
  var x = document.forms["newsletterForm"]["name"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must not be blank");
    return false;
  } else if (!regex.test(x)) {
    alert("Name contains invalid characters (letters and spaces only!)");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="newsletterForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name*: </label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Fill in your name"> <br><br>
  <label for="email">E-mail*: </label><br>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Fill in your e-mail address"><br><br>
  <label for="comments">Comments (optional): </label> <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Leave us a message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for that!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use regex for that

```js
var regexExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;

function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["newsletterForm"]["name"].value;
 alert(x)
    if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("Name must not be blank");
            return false;
        }
       
    else if (!regexExp.test(x)) {
            alert("Name contains invalid characters (letters and spaces only!)")
            return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="newsletterForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                <label for="name">Name*: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Fill in your name"1> <br><br>
                <label for="email">E-mail*: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Fill in your e-mail address"><br><br>
                <label for="comments">Comments (optional): </label> <br>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Leave us a message"></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `typeof`

try

```
if(x == null || typeof x !== 'string')
{
   //code here
}
```

An empty string isn't a valid value to check against.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that, I'll change that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the problem is your use of `!==`. `!==` would be looking for an absolute match between `x` and your regular expression object - that is, is `x` that regular expression object; not does it *match* that expression.

What about this:

`else if (! /^[A-Za-z ]+$/.test(x))`